# Java generic method to get arbitrary data from a provider

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to find an elegant solution for this, but can't figure out.

I have somewhere a generic data provider. I want to call it to get arbitrary objects - and it will get them from cache, server, etc., depending of the request.

I want to call it like this, for example:

```
List<Customer> customers = new DataProvider().getData(new CustomersRequest(20));
```

This will provide me all customers with age 20. DataProvider decides how and where to get this data.

Where CustomersRequest extends a Request class.

To get this working getData needs to make instanceOf checks on the Request instance, and call the corresponding methods from DB cache or remote provider... something like:

```
if (request instanceof CustomersRequest) {
    DBDataProvider dbDataProvider = new DBDataProvider();
    List<Customer> customers = dbDataProvider.getCustomers(request);

    if (customers == null) {
        RemoteDataProvider removeDataProvider = new RemoteDataProvider();
        customers = removeDataProvider.getCustomers(request);

        if (request.cacheInDB) {
            //save response to db
        }

        return customers;

    }

}
```

But that only works if I return an `Object` from this method - which would make me do a cast each time I call it. I assume this is the suitable solution although, since I'm basing the returned data also on casting I do inside.

And instance of is said to be bad.

I couldn't find a way to solve this with generics.

I could also do:

```
List<Customer> customers = new DataProvider().getCostumers(20);
```

But this would mean, that I have to create many methods in DataProvider, for all my different objects and parameters, and in each of these methods, call a common method, which will to the cache checks and other things. With this common method, I have the same problem as in the first approach.

Or also:

```
List<Customer> customers = new CustomersDataProvider().getCostumers(20);
```

here I have no more problems with instance of and generics, since it's not generic anymore. But not sure if I can abstract this correctly in order to get the caching access and validations in 1 place for all the possible data.

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: If you're going to have many different ways to get a customer, create a CustomerProfile class.  You would set the customer parameters in an instance of the CustomerProfile class, and your DataProvider would use the instance to determine what data to get.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case where the class `Class` is useful. You can have your method like this:

```
List<Customer> customers = new DataProvider().getCostumers(20, Customer.class);
```

the signature of your method would be something like:

```
T getCostumer(int age, Class<T> clazz)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have a switch anyway, should you use instanceof, getClass(), or constant strings.

My preference would go to constant strings, I find them better if you want to design an API that can be called by external users.

It is not that bad to have a switch, as long as you do not multiply them in your application. You can use basic oop techniques based on interfaces in order to keep only one switch.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think the elegant solution here is to add a `getDBDataProvider` method to the `Request` class.  Now `getData` doesn't have to worry about whether or not `CustomerRequest` is a `Request`.  (Only about whether the return is null or not.)  The responsibility for getting the right `DBDataProvider` rests with the method override in `CustomerRequest`, which doesn't need `instanceof` or reflection to know that it is indeed a `CustomerRequest`.

In general, to be elegant, I think the superclasses and interfaces should have enough methods to handle the needs of all their subclasses/implementations.  This means a lot of the working code doesn't have to deal with subclasses, and code written for one specific subclass will automatically work for all.

I think a lot of times you're better off just using `instanceof`.  You'll write less code and finish sooner.  You don't have to put null (or trivial) methods into classes they don't really apply to.  But if you expect to build on what you're doing this approach is a much better way to go.